# InterpolatingPolynomial defining x

Tags: interpolation

So InterpolatingPolynomial use integer x values? 
How do i manipulate them?
InterpolatingPolynomial[FUNCTION of x, x]

Guess i quite don't get the function definition cause my code is not working properly

I want to use the function for defined x range

```
xk[k_, n_] := (-1 + (k)*(2/(n)))
f[x_] := 1/(1 + 25 x^2)
fk[n_] := Table[f[xk[i, n]], {i, 0, n}]
PlotPoint[x_] := 
 ListPlot[Table[{xk[i, x], Part[fk[x], i + 1]}, {i, 0, x}]]
PlotLine[x_] := Plot[f[i], {i, xk[0, x], xk[x, x]}]
Show[PlotLine[10], PlotPoint[10]]

getMatrix[N_] := 
 Table[If[j == 1, 1, xk[i - 1, N - 1]^(j - 1)], {i, N}, {j, N}]
Lin := LinearSolve[getMatrix[5], Table[fk[k, 3], {k, 0, 3}]]
c[n_] := LinearSolve[getMatrix[n + 1], fk[n]]
p1[x_, n_] := Sum[Part[c[n], i + 1]*x^i, {i, 0, n}]
PlotPoly := Plot[p1[i, 4], {i, xk[0, 4], xk[4, 4]}]
PlotPoly
Show[PlotPoly, PlotPoint[4], PlotLine[4]]

l[x_, i_, n_] := 
 Product[If[j != i, (x - xk[j, n])/(xk[i, n] - xk[j, n]), 1], {j, 0, 
   n}]
l[xk[3, 10], 4, 10]
p2[x_, n_] := Sum[f[xk[k, n]]*l[x, k, n], {k, 0, n}]
Plot[p2[i, 4], {i, xk[0, 4], xk[4, 4]}]

Plot[InterpolatingPolynomial[f[x], x], {x, xk[0, 4], xk[4, 4]}]
```

Edit1:

```
Plot3 := Plot[
  InterpolatingPolynomial[{f[x]}, x], {x, xk[0, 4], xk[4, 4]}]
```

Any ideas how to set this up such Plot3 equals p2 and p1?

Comment: What is it that you want `InterpolatingPolynomial` to do? The way you have it set up in `Plot3`, all that is happening is you're plotting your `f[x]` and `InterpolatingPolynomial` isn't actually doing anything. For `InterpolatingPolynomial` to work, you need to send it some data points. Do you want to feed it the data points created by your initial `PlotPoint` function?

Comment: Yes my script tells me that the plot with InterpolatingPolynomial (xk and f) should be the same plot as my ```Plot[p2[i, 4], {i, xk[0, 4], xk[4, 4]}]``` and p1

Comment: @Rapiz You will need to describe what you need quite a bit better. You will also want to remove any code in your question that does not pertain to the question directly. Right now I think this is more confusing than it needs to be.

Comment: So my function for supporting values are defined by ```f[x_]``` and my supporting  points are defined by ```xk[k_,n_] ```                        I calculated the interpolation polynom with ```p1``` and ```p2```                    Now i want to calculate my interpolation polymom with ```InterpolationPolynomial[]``` and plot it.                                          My script tells me that it should look the same as ```p1``` and ```p2```.          So the plot should be equal to ```PlotPoly``` and ```Plot[p2[i, 4], {i, xk[0, 4], xk[4, 4]}]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica, there is a difference between `Set (=)` and `SetDelayed (:=)`. `SetDelayed` is often used when you're defining a function because you want to define it now but not actually evaluate it until you have a number to plug into it,  and you will probably evaluate it repeatedly. `Set` means that the code will be executed immediately and the result stored in your variable. Your code isn't too computationally intensive, but defining something like `Plot3 := Plot[...]` means that the plotting algorithm must be called everytime you write `Plot3`. In these cases, usually you just want `plot3 = Plot[...]` so that it is evaluated just once and then stored. Also, I recommend against using uppercase variable/function names to avoid collisions with built-in functions.

As for using `InterpolatingPolynomial`, it needs to have a set of data points. One possibility is:

```
points[n_] := Transpose[{#, f[#]} &@xk[Range[0, n], n]]
intplt[n_] := Plot[InterpolatingPolynomial[points[n], x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red]
Show[
  PlotLine[x],
  PlotPoint[4],
  intplt[4],
  PlotRange -> Full
]
```

[image: Plot of function and interpolating polynomial.]

If you're new to Mathematica, the `Slot (#)` notation is probably a bit confusing. They are essentially placeholders and are just waiting for something to be slotted into them. So my `{#, f[#]} &@ xk[Range[0, n], n]` is equivalent to `{xk[Range[0, n], n], f[xk[Range[0, n], n]}`. The `&` character is the signal that the slots should be filled with whatever comes after it, and the `@` symbol is the same as using square brackets `[ ]` around the code, but I already had a lot of square brackets so I felt it looked cleaner with `@`.

My `xk[Range[0, n], n]` might also look strange, but many built-in function as well as custom functions have the property `Listable`. This means that if you give it a list of values, it will provide an output for each of the inputs. In the case of $n=4$, `Range[0, 4]` produces the list `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}` so we have `xk[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 4]`. It will then perform the calculation `{xk[0, 4], xk[1, 4], xk[2, 4], xk[3, 4], xk[4, 4]}` and return the result. The same thing can be achieved using `Table` but `Listable` functions can be many times faster.

I'm also using `Transpose` to turn 2 lists into a series of $(x, y)$ data points, which is what `InterpolatingPolynomial` is expecting. Thus, `points[4]` generates the list `{{-1, 1/26}, {-(1/2), 4/29}, {0, 1}, {1/2, 4/29}, {1, 1/26}}`.

Comment: I'm way more confused about InterpolatingPolynomial, isn't the x in the documentation the list that gives the f it's x values ?

Comment: Tried to use ```InterpolatingPolynomial[fk[4],Table[xk[i,4],{i,0,4}]]``` but that one failed as well

Comment: @Rapiz No, it's not. The `x` can be any variable name you want. For example, you could have `InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 5}}, myvariable]` and it will return `myvariable^2 + 1`. The `x` should not contain any data itself, it's just a convenient way to specify which variable you'd like to use to write the polynomial. If you try `InterpolatingPolynomial[{1, 2, 5}, x]`, it assumes the values you give are y-values and assumes the x-values are `{1, 2, 3}` (many functions in Mathematica make this assumption if you only give them y-data).